# Can't run .exe file on another computer

Tags: c++, executable, open3d

I'm trying to figure out why my application will not run on another windows computer. I have tried to run the exe file on multiple other computers where it starts the application up fine, however, when running it on a Teguar running windows 10, the application throws an exception.

It seems like the problem accurs when I try to use Open3D, since when I don't include Open3D the application can run on the computer. However, the program can still run on all other computers with Open3D included just not on the Teguar.

I have tried to run the exe file through "SimpleProgramDebugger" and here I can see what files are called. This is the files from my own computer where the program runs fine.
[image: Image from SimpleProgramDebugger]

Here is an image of the files from the Teguar:
[image]
And lastly here is the message on I am given when simply running the application:
[image: Exception when running application]
Hopefully someone can help with this frustrating problem :)

Comment: `0xc000001d` is an illegal instruction error, presumably the CPU doesn't support all the instructions used in your application, you'll need to recompile with those instructions disabled

Comment: The error code `0xc000001d` stands for `STATUS_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION`. Maybe the software is compiled to use CPU instructions that are only available in newer CPUs and the Teguar is using an older CPU which does not have these instructions. What is the exact CPU model of the Teguar on which the problem occurs?

Comment: Thanks for the answers to both of you. @AndreasWenzel the exact Processor is Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU N3710 1.6GHz

Comment: @mikkelsen1996: That CPU is based on the [Silvermont microarchitecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silvermont) and is therefore not too old, so it should support all modern software, as long as that software is not compiled to use [AVX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions). Did you compile Open3D yourself or are you using a pre-built binary?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel´: I'm using Open3D as a pre-built binary at the moment.

Comment: @mikkelsen1996: According to [this page](https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/issues/5435), Open3D requires AVX by default, which the CPU you mentioned does not support. See [this page](https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/issues/4970) on how to compile Open3D without AVX support.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel thank you for the help. I will look into that, however I don't seems to have the embree file that is mention in your last link.

Comment: have you downloaded the source code? The file is definitely there https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/blob/master/3rdparty/embree/embree.cmake

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: Ohh I fought I could do it from the binaries. I will try that now thx

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I have still not been able to solve my problem.. When I build the source with the configurations mentioned [here](https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/issues/4970)  I get the error messages " error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in Open3DConfig.obj" I have search for similar problems on Open3D issue site but the only one I found was not resolved. Is this something you might know how to fix?

Comment: @mikkelsen1996: I'm sorry, I do not have any experience in building the Open3D library, so I have no idea what that could be. You may want to post a new question about this on Stack Overflow. You may also want to consider posting it [as an issue of Open3D on github](https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/issues).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I manage to make it work on the Teguar computer. I had forgot disable the 'STATIC_WINDOWS_RUNTIME' and also enable 'BUILD_WEBRTC:FROM_SOURCE' when I made that configuration while also doing what was mentioned in the link you provided I was able to run it. With that said what previous took me around 5 seconds to compute now takes around 10 minutes on the Teguar. I think the solution will be a hardware upgrade, but thank you for the help anyway :)

Comment: @mikkelsen1996: It was to be expected that disabling AVX would lead to a significant performance degredation. However, a factor of 120 does seem excessive. I would have expected maybe a factor of 2. The CPU you are using does not support AVX, but it does support SSE4.2. One of the links I posted also contains instructions on how to enable SSE4.2 instead of AVX.

Comment: @mikkelsen1996: I am not familiar with the build process of Open3D, but you should also ensure that you are not creating a "debug" build, because such builds are much slower than fully optimized builds. Therefore, if you have the option between a "debug" build and a "release" build, you should choose the "release" build.